# Entity Framework: Entity is cached when update and reselecting it in a stored procedure using a function import

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

I'm using EF4 with Visual Studio 2010 and SQL Server 2008 R2.

I am selecting an entity. After that I call a stored procedure which updates that entity en reselects it from the database. When I catch the result of the stored procedure in code, I see that the old (previously selected) properties.

Obviously I'm looking at the cached entity value. Is there a way to signal EF that my entity was updated? Or a magic property of some sort?

My database table (and entity) look something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [Message]
(
    ID int IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
    Content XML,
    StateID int NOT NULL,
)
```

My SP is something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_Queue_s
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @queue table ([ID] int NOT NULL)
    BEGIN TRAN
        INSERT INTO @queue
        SELECT [ID]
        FROM [Message]
        WHERE   StateID = 1

        UPDATE [Message]
        SET StateID = 2
        WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM @queue)
    COMMIT TRAN
    -- Select the queue
    SELECT [ID], [Content], [Message]
    FROM [Message]
    WHERE [ID] IN (SELECT ID FROM @queue)
END
```

My C# code looks something like this:

```
using (var context = new MyEntities())
            {
                int id = 1;
                var message = context.Messages.Single(m => m.ID == id);
                var messages = context.GetQueue(); // Function import of sp_Queue_s, maps on the Message entity
                var messageUpdated = messages.Single(m => m.ID == id);
            }
```

Comment: Can you show the code generated by EF for `GetQueue` method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GetQueue` should be a generated method internally calling `context.ExecuteFunction`. `ExecuteFunction` has multiple overloads and one of them accepts `MergeOption`. Try to call `ExecuteFunction` directly with `MergeOption.OverwriteChanges`.

Comment: Thanks man! You made my day! Why isn't this the default merge option?