# Why does the old value stay in this object after it is reset?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio, entity-framework

I've shown three programmers this problem and we're all stumped. I call a Sql Server stored procedure in a foreach loop and the result always is the same as the first call. **Even if I hard code parameters (removing the loop) only the first result is assigned to all subsequent calls.**

The stored procedure is called by an Entity Framework function import (EF4 database first using the designer). The calling code lives in a repository that is a class library. The repository is called by a separate Asp.net webforms project. The problem code looks like this:

```
IEnumerable<WorkOrder> orders = _context.GetWorkOrders(UserName, workOrder, customerCode).ToList();

OrderStatus lastStatus = new OrderStatus();

foreach (Order order in orders)
{
     lastStatus = _context.GetOrderStatus(order.OrderNumber).FirstOrDefault();
     order.LastOrderStatus = lastStatus.OrderStatus;
}
```

As you can see this is pretty basic stuff. Depending on the order numbers passed in I always get the result of the first order number in the loop. I've turned off Ajax (part of the Telerik controls I use) because that has caused baffling errors for me in the past. I really hope you can suggest a way to debug this problem! Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Daniel J.G.'s comment led me to [this possible solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8311766/entity-framework-entity-is-cached-when-update-and-reselecting-it-in-a-stored-pr). Now I need to figure out how to apply Ladislav Mrnka's answer..."**Try to call ExecuteFunction directly with MergeOption.OverwriteChanges**."

Comment: Can you show how you populate orders please?

Comment: The most likely explanation is that GetWorkOrders isn't doing what you think it's doing.

Comment: We need to see the code for GetWorkOrders() and GetOrderStatus()

Comment: I'm sure you checked it, but is GetWorkOrders returning more than one order?

Comment: Even if its just one order it should be called just once.
Check the code again and check `orders` content. Debug it, break it when `orders` is populated and see the content

Comment: GetWorkOrders and GetOrderStatus are returning the expected values outside of visual studio. I see in debug mode that different order numbers are passed in. I've even used Sql Profiler and seen that the calls are all accurate.

Comment: I'm fairly certain you can't assign values to the iterated object in a foreach loop.  You cannot alter the contents of the collection you're iterating through while you're iterating through it.  You could either be filling a different collection or you need to use a for loop rather than a foreach.

Comment: This could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7802015/entity-framework-problems-retrieving-cached-values-instead-of-recent-changes

Comment: @post_erasmus is right, you are basically changing the scope of the loop while its running.

Comment: Even without the last line the problem remains. If I replace it with Console.WriteLine(lastStatus.OrderStatus); I still see the problem.

Comment: @post_erasmus Nope, you can definitely do that - you just can't reassign the variable to a different object, but you can call methods or properties on that object all you want.

Comment: @JoeEnos You can for sure call them, but I'm fairly certain that you cannot make persistent changes to an iterated object ("order", in this case) while the iterator is running.  In this case, the LastOrderStatus property of every object in orders will be the same after the foreach loop as it was before the foreach loop, no matter what order.LastOrderStatus is set to.

Comment: Another alternative would be to use a new context with each call. Looks like that might not be too easy with your repository pattern, but it would definitely remove any caching issues.

Comment: @post_erasmus An instance of object is not being iterated, A variable (that references an instance of object) is, and the code is not changing the variable, merely the object it references. If you attempted to change the itereated variable then it would not let you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm answering my own question (since no one else has after a few days). The problem is caused by the Entity Framework database first designer. It generates code that caches the first stored procedure result causing the bad results in subsequent calls.

As I mentioned in the edit to my question **the fix involves replacing the default MergeOption parameter used by ExecuteFunction. You need to use MergeOption.OverwriteChanges instead of the default** (which I believe is MergeOption.PreserveChanges).

You *could* change that parameter in the generated code but your changes would be lost each time the designer is rebuilt. Instead I simply copied the generated code to my repository class, changed the MergeOption to OverwriteChanges, and stopped using the generated code. The end result looks like this:

```
IEnumerable<WorkOrder> orders = _context.GetWorkOrders(UserName, workOrder, customerCode).ToList();

OrderStatus lastStatus = new OrderStatus();

foreach (Order order in orders)
{

    ObjectParameter workOrderParameter;
    if (wo.WorkOrder != null)
    {
        workOrderParameter = new ObjectParameter("WorkOrder", order.WorkOrder);
    }
    else
    {
       workOrderParameter = new ObjectParameter("WorkOrder", typeof(global::System.String));
    }

    lastStatus = _context.ExecuteFunction<OrderStatus>("GetOrderStatus", MergeOption.OverwriteChanges, workOrderParameter).FirstOrDefault();

    if (status != null)
    {
        order.LastOrderStatus = status.OrderStatus;
    }
}
```

I also see that there is a way you can modify the T4 template to make the generated code use the correct MergeOption parameter. I haven't tried it though. If you're interested [take a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13868311/map-a-stored-procedure-to-entity-framework-with-mergeoption).

Answer (score 1):

I'm back with a second answer to my own question. **Be sure the Entity Key is truly a unique identifier for each Entity!**

In my case, the OrderStock Entity was missing the OrderID (along with StockID) as the Entity Key. Typically the designer culls the primary key fields from the database but I have a unique situation (where my entity is based on a view). Since I left off OrderID from the Entity Key I saw duplicate rows for a single OrderStock Entity.

When I marked OrderID `Entity Key = True` the duplicate problem went away.